# How do I pull both categories AND tags from a MySQL Database for an item?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I have 5 tables in my database. 
[Items] - id, name, etc... 
[Categories] - id, name
[Tags] - id, name

2 Joining tables
[Items_Categories] - item_id, category_id
[Items_Tags] - item_id, tag_id

I simply need to know the best performing query (using JOINS as necessary) to pull 1 or more items from the DB WITH all of it's information, including the Categories AND Tags, given the item_id = $id.

So Far, I have the following which works, but on 25 - 50 queries, it was slow (Does anyone have something better?):

```
    SELECT `items`.`name`, `items`.`etc`,
group_concat(DISTINCT categories.name ORDER BY categories.name DESC SEPARATOR ", ") AS category, 
group_concat(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR ", ") AS tag, 
`items`.`id` AS id 
FROM (`items` AS items, `item_categories` AS categories, `items_to_categories` AS items_cats, `item_tags` AS tags, `items_to_tags` AS items_tags) 
JOIN `item_categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `items_cats`.`category_id` AND items_cats.item_id = $id 
JOIN `item_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `items_tags`.`tag_id` AND items_tags.item_id = $id WHERE `items`.`id` = $id
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT first, then join. Use subqueries.

Comment: There's nothing simple about finding the best performing query. Prefix your query with Explain and run it, and put the result in your question, all we can do is guess at the moment.

Comment: Subqueries are almost always a red-flag to my query-writing eyes. Also, I think there are some "simple" techniques to get onto a very performant footing. The really tough part is in ultra-tweaking the performance; but I haven't noticed a real need for that (with well designed queries) until there are millions of rows. 9 times out of 10, simply understanding how the query plan will be built based on your sql will enable you to write queries which are many orders of magnitude more efficient (if your schema is good).

Comment: Oh I wouldn't recommend subqueries, but I don't recommend guessing either. :( Unless it's a barkingly obvious, missing index) Explain is job one. If it is an obvious index , then explain is job two, just to make sure me and the DBMS are on the same page.

Comment: @ctrahey: Couldn't have said this better myself. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the subquery remark was in response to the first commenter. The rest is essentially adding one thing to your list (as my "job one"): built a smart query by knowing how your RDBMS does JOINs.

Comment: @ctrahey, think we might have got off track then. A sub-query would be a red flag for me as well. My approach would be to make sure I had a suitable index for the join(s) I'm about to replace it with first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually doing a full cross join first (by listing the tables the way you did) instead of joining selectively "in order" and allowing the joins to be streamlined by the query plan. Try joining like this to explicitly join only the appropriate rows as it goes.

```
SELECT 
  `items`.`name`, 
  `items`.`etc`,
  group_concat(DISTINCT `categories`.`name` ORDER BY `categories`.`name` DESC SEPARATOR ", ") AS category, 
  group_concat(DISTINCT `tags`.`name` ORDER BY `tags`.`name` DESC SEPARATOR ", ") AS tag, 
  `items`.`id` AS id 
FROM `items`, 
  LEFT JOIN `item_categories` ON `items`.`id` = `item_categories`.`item_id`
  LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `item_categories`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`,
  LEFT JOIN `item_tags` ON `items`.`id` = `item_tags`.`item_id`
  LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `item_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
WHERE `item`.`id` = $id
GROUP BY `item`.`id`
```

This will yield a lightening-fast query, and it is easily made even faster by adding the appropriate indexes. My philosophy, however, is that you should have a fast query first, and then get it wicked fast with indexing; not using indexes as a first-approach.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm, and is a noticeable improvement.